# Create grid border programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Good morning,

I'm creating columns in a grid programmatically and I need borders for each cell.
I let "showGridLines" as true, but I know that this is not right, 'cause those gridLines aren't for production.
How can I set borders to every cell programmatically?

The following code shows how I'm creating the columns:

```
        public void ColumnCreator(double divPattern, DateTime initial, DateTime final) 
        {   
        double leftMargin = 0;
        int initialPosition =  (int) SecondsFromMidnight(initial);  
        TimeSpan interval = final.Subtract(initial);
        int divisionPattern = Convert.ToInt16(divPattern);
        int increaseLabelTime = 0;
        AddLabel(initial, leftMargin);

        for (int i = initialPosition; i <=  (initialPosition+ interval.TotalSeconds); i += divisionPattern)
        {
            DateTime dt = initial;
            internalGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(divisionPattern, 
                GridUnitType.Pixel) });
            leftMargin += divisionPattern;
            increaseLabelTime += divisionPattern;
            dt = dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, increaseLabelTime));
            AddLabel(dt, leftMargin);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Border` in each cell, and add contents to the `Border`'s `Content`. Set the `BorderThickness` and `BorderColor` accordingly.